# automating testing website that require OTP, using Selenium, Node.js, Lambda(AWS)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, selenium, aws-lambda, devops

My project is automating testing website using Selenium in AWS lambda(Node.js)
However, The testing website require mobile OTP(Google Authenticator) when users sign in.
I searched how to write code to automate sign in with OTP. but most of answers are using Python or java (pyotp or aerogear)...
We can't use another language and must use Lambda
Please help me!

Comment: Can you python script which does that? You can bundle extra dependencies, e.g. `pyotp` with your lambda function.

Comment: #Marcin No I can't do that, just googling if someone wants to use bring OTP form mobile by Python. I'm not sure can do on Lambda

Answer (score 0):

You can run the python script in Lambda no problem there.
Write a python file, zip it, upload it to Lambda function.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcprG.png)
Just select the version(runtime) of python you want to use in configuration tab of the lambda function.

Comment: Yes! I agree your answer and thank you. However, my coworker already wrote code that testing website using Selenium(without OTP) by Node.js... we just want to add a function that bring OTP from moblie automatically in coworker code.
It risk is very high if we are change language.....

Comment: Ok in that case I dont have much knowledge with NodeJs so cant help much.